# Regex for localized paths

Tags: ruby, regex

What can I do to make this regex match '`/en/`' and '`/en`'? (edit: as well as '/en/foo') It matches '`/en/foo`'.

```
:locales = %w[en ja]
:pattern = /^\/?(#{Regexp.union(:locales)})(\/.+)$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:pattern = /^\/?(#{Regexp.union(:locales)})\/?$/
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this match '/en/foo' as well?